# What is insecure about hard-coding a password inside an application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, authentication

I need to create a basic login for a single page of my ASP.NET MVC application and I'm debating whether I should spend hours trying to learn about the Identity library, SALTing passwords, etc. or whether I can just do the following.

So I use [Password Depot](http://www.password-depot.com/) to create a random password like

```
g5\oLH*aFZn=mL5GKS@5&P%*
```

about which it says

> Estimated time to crack the password: 7.37*10^30 years.

and then I'm going to store that in the application in give to the customer. The login will be a simple

```
    [HttpPost] 
    public ActionResult TryLogin ( string pwsdAttempt )
    {
        if ( AdminController.CheckPassword(pwsdAttempt) )
        {
            Session["loggedIn"] = "true";
            return Json(new { correct = true });
        }
        else
        {
            return Json( new { correct = false });
        }

    }
```

that checks `pswdAttempt` against the `g5\oLH*aFZn=mL5GKS@5&P%*` (or whatever the randomly generated password ends up being) and this will be over a SSL.

Are there any potential problems with that? If so, what, and why?

Comment: If the password is generated server side, transmitted through SSL to the client, and the client does not save it anywhere, then yes, it's secure.  Don't take this to mean that your login system is secure.  Just the password.  Personally I'd still let a user make their own password and just hash and salt it server side...

Comment: @MsYvette While the question was unclear, and David Brossard had edited it according to his answer, I rolled it back, to avoid wrong upvotes. I hoped OP can edit his question to make it more clear. But now, since David's answer is accepted, his interpratation appears to be correct. This is why I don't rollback it again... I find all these discussions unfair without resorting to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you should spend the time researching security. It doesn't take much time and there are standard frameworks that do the heavy lifting for you.

What do you mean when you write

> and then I'm going to store that in the application in give to the customer.

?

Your approach has several issues.

### Really bad security

First of all, any bit of text you write (be it code, strings, or in your case a password) that is then compiled can always be reverse engineered and retrieved. Some languages are tougher, some easier. Take a sample Java .class file and "decompile" it and you will be pretty close to the original.

This means that your password can be retrieved from the app. Not a good idea. Not great security.

**You should never ever store a password in the clear**. You should always hash it and salt it too. Quoting Wikipedia

> A salt is random data that is used as an additional input to a one-way
>   function that "hashes" a password or passphrase. The primary function
>   of salts is to defend against dictionary attacks versus a list of
>   password hashes and against pre-computed rainbow table attacks.

Actually, if you are a developer, then you should let the security pros take care of security. That's why security frameworks exist in the first place. Rely on them. Do not reinvent the wheel, especially not the security wheel.

### Bad Management

Does it mean you have to recompile and redeploy to change your password?

### Bad UX

The other aspect of course is UX. Why would you hard-code a password? Don't you want your users to choose their own passwords? While you are at it, don't you want more than one user? Also wouldn't you want the user to use an account they already have e.g. something in Active Directory?

### Further Reading

- [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)

Comment: Just one thing: hashing and salting are useless in case of a generated strong password.

Comment: Noooooo! No they are not! Read more here: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: @KooKiz That's exactly my point

Comment: Hm ok, after more thinking, I agree that hashing improves the security, as the attacker still can't log in after reverse-engineering the code (it means that he has access to the server so the app is already pretty much pwnd, but that's beside the point). Salting though, I don't see. The point of salting is protecting the password from rainbow table. But since the password is autogenerated and about 20 chars long, there's no need to add additional complexity via salting

Comment: David, fully agree to your points. However as per the decompilation concerns - I'm no expert on ASP.NET, but I'd assume dlls are somewhere on the server not accessible from the outside, i.e. no outside users would be able to get their hands on them in order to decompile in the first place?

Comment: You still have to protect yourself against external attacks. Take Ashley Madison, Adobe... All the data was server-side. It didn't stop hackers from getting access.

Comment: @KooKiz So do you think that security experts recommend salting for no reason? Remember, they're the experts, not you.

Comment: @mason I'm not saying salting is useless, I'm saying salting is useless in case of a single strong password generated server-side. There's two points in salting: first, making it impossible to see from the hashes whether two passwords are identical or not. This is not relevant since there is only one password on the website. Second: rendering rainbow table useless by making sure that the password is long enough and not sensible to dictionary attack. Both are irrelevant because the password is random and long enough. If you know a third benefit, let's hear it out.

Comment: @mason Also, please note that I'm debating for the sake of furthering my knowledge as well as the one of all the people take part in the discussion.  I really don't care about whether OP ends up salting his password or not. So please let's keep the "experts said so" out of the discussion and try instead to understand why they said so

Comment: @KooKiz This question will be seen by many people who will not understand the difference between the various scenarios. And if salting is free, why *not* use it?  Hash and salt, every time.

Comment: @mason `And if salting is free, why not use it? Hash and salt, every time` I think you don't ( want to? ) understand what KooKiz tries to say....